# Use Constant or Class Variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, constants, class-variables

I am showing a number of navigation links on a page.
It will be fixed in the application but in the future could change, but not interactively, just if a new release changed it.  So fixed within the application in use.

The number of links is set for use within many different actions in the controller.

Should I use a class level variable `@@number_of_link`s to make it stay within the class and allow other uses (different controllers and models say) of the same name without conflict (i.e. scoped), or should I use a constant like `NumberOfLinks`?

I've been given advice on both and would like to confirm my preference for the first.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking; if it's an application-wide constant, it should be an application-wide constant. If it's a class-level constant, it should be a class-level constant.

Comment: Hey Dave thanks +1.  When you say class-level constant, in practice does that just mean a variable declared outside of any method? Any pre-fix? Upper Case?

Comment: I should give a bit more info on how it changes.  I will add that for more clarity, it will change it a bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's definitely not a constant unless it's constant!

Instead of a class variable, I'd suggest a class-instance variable. You get all the benefits of a class variable, with even better scoping (other members of the class won't clobber the value, and easier access too.

```
class Foo

  class << self
    def number_of_links
      @number_of_links ||= 10 # or some sensible default, you might make this a constant to highlight the number when you're reading the code.
    end

    def number_of_links=( n )
      @number_of_links = n
    end
  end
end

puts Foo.number_of_links
# => 10
Foo.number_of_links = 20

puts Foo.number_of_links
# => 20
```

see http://blog.codegram.com/2011/4/understanding-class-instance-variables-in-ruby for more.

Comment: Thanks. +1  I will check out the link.

Answer (score 2):

If it will only be changed with a new release of the software then make it a constant. That better reflects the intent of that value.

Values that won't be changed by application logic do not need to be transient variables. I avoid class variables (and class instance variables) when possible because many developers have trouble understanding the difference between the two, when to use them, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Like Iain says.. use **class instance variables**.. but you can reduce that code using attr_accessor

```
class Foo
  class << self; attr_accessor :number_of_links; end
  self.number_of_links = 10 #default value..
end

puts Foo.number_of_links
# => 10
Foo.number_of_links = 20

puts Foo.number_of_links
# => 20
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is something of a strict nature that you don't plan on modifying with application logic you should use a constant.

If it is something you expect to change with the state of the class (if it is extrapolated based on the state of a database interaction) you should use a class variable.

From a performance perspective it doesn't matter, in this case, using it the way described above you can assume the intent using the type of variable which makes it easier for contributing developers to understand without "decoding".

Comment: A constant sounds good but I was thinking that if num_of_links was ever used elsewhere, it would be better to scope it to this class.  Seems like it would be safer ?

Comment: Yes, NUM_OF_LINKS is a bit ambiguous.  A constant must start with a capital letter so the only way you could have a "conflict" is if you reassign the constant, which is possible in ruby.  Again, convention is king over cleverness.  If it something that will not change, another person can learn a lot about your app from evaluating the constants of your application.

Answer (score 0):

let's say you need to update number of links if you do it over constant ruby will warn like this "warning: already initialized constant NumOfLinks"

in such case you should stick with class variable.